# Odoo notebook position

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

Odoo 10

I want to move a notebook page but having errors when I do so. I want to move the membership notebook before the Contacts & Addresses

[image]

In the Membership addon I replaced `<notebook position="inside">` to before but this did not work and crashed Odoo with error ParseError: "Invalid view definition

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Membership">
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="free_member"/>
                                <label for="membership_state"/>
                                <div>
                                    <field name="membership_state"/>
                                    <button name="%(action_membership_invoice_view)d" type="action" string="Buy Membership" 
                                        attrs="{'invisible':[('free_member','=',True)]}" class="oe_link"/>
                                </div>
                            </group>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with an xpath:

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[1]" position="before">
   <page string="Membership">
       <group>
          <group>
             <field name="free_member"/>
             <label for="membership_state"/>
              <div>
                  <field name="membership_state"/>
                  <button name="%(action_membership_invoice_view)d" type="action" string="Buy Membership" 
                    attrs="{'invisible':[('free_member','=',True)]}" class="oe_link"/>
               </div>
           </group>
        </group>
   </page>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I aslo had to remove the auto focas for the Membership to open first.